# focusing not applied on text box through angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making text boxes with a directive and want only the first text box to be in focus.
 I am using another directive for focus. This is the script:

```
<script>
angular.module('MyApp',[]);
angular.module('MyApp').controller('myController',myController);
angular.module('MyApp').directive('myDirective',myDirective);

angular.module('MyApp').directive('textBoxDirective',textBoxDirective);

function myController()
{

}



function myDirective()
{
    return{

        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
                abcd:'='
        },
           link : function(scope, $element) {
               console.log(""+scope.abcd);
               if(scope.abcd=='true'){
                   $element[0].focus();
               }


                } 
    };  
}

 function textBoxDirective()
{
    return{
        scope:{
            efgh:'@'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<input type="text" data-my-directive="" data-abcd="efgh">'

    };  
} 

</script>
```

This is the html:

```
   <body data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="myController">

<div data-text-box-directive="" data-efgh="true"></div>
<div data-text-box-directive=""></div>
<div data-text-box-directive=""></div>
</body>
```

I am getting the value of `abcd` as true in `myDirective` once and `undefined` twice on logging but still the focusing is not applied on the first textbox. What am I doing wrong here ? Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout(function () {
   if($element && $element[0]){
    $element[0].focus();
   }
});
```